# Captcha is not displaying in RSForm pro in joomla 1.5 site

Tags: preg-replace, joomla1.5, captcha

I have hosted a joomla 1.5 website few months back. It's contact form is done by using rsform pro and it worked properly without any issue. But since last week the form doesn't show the CAPTCHA image. When i searched the folder structure, i found several files of php and images that I didn't insert in. Php files has a preg_replace and function.unlink too.

Please help me to solve this.